# Compress Bitmap to ASTC runtime on Android

Tags: android, textures, opengl-es-2.0

I have used ETCUtil in the past to convert a PNG/Bitmap to a ETC1 compressed texture runtime and it served me well. I was wondering if, with the introduction of ASTC support in Android L, there is also a way to do the same with ASTC, even with third party libraries.

I am not looking for a generic, PC based compressor but a Java / Native library that runs on the phone.

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for an iOS 10 / macOS Sierra (and later) solution, this is now a feature of ImageIO.framework.  See also /usr/include/AppleTextureEncoder.h